# jwplayer error with video

Tags: php, jwplayer

I have an error with my jwplayer. I've just coded a simple video site and every time I try to view it there is an error

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FKTWTV!</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
<script src="jwplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
?>

<div id='box'>

<?php
    $video = $_GET['video'];
?>
<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="100%" height="315">
        <param name="movie" value="jwplayer/player-licensed-viral.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4&image=preview.jpg" />
        <embed
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            id="player2"
            name="player2"
            src="jwplayer/player-licensed-viral.swf" 
            width="100%" 
            height="400"
            allowscriptaccess="always" 
            allowfullscreen="true"
            flashvars="file=videos/<?php echo $video; ?>&image=jwplayer/preview.jpg" 
        />
    </object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is saying 'access denied' or 'video not found'.  What could be wrong?

Comment: Every time you try to view a video it comes up with *what* error?

Comment: Try to craft a minimal example. You're including `connect.php`, but don't appear to be using it. Make an example which leaves it out. Try creating valid HTML (start by escaping those ampersands). Tell us exactly what error you're seeing. You say "this error", but don't actually quote an error message. If the rendering seems off, include a screenshot. You can [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: http://fktwtv.com/error.png - thats the error i get

Comment: Don't hide information in comments. Most people don't bother reading them. You can [edit] the information into the post (the editor includes an image upload button). Also, try to tidy your grammar a bit while you're at it. Proper casing makes it easier to read. There's a difference between *ill* and *I'll*.

Comment: Can you provide a link?